# Ruby + Cucumber: How to execute cucumber in code?

Tags: ruby, dynamic, cucumber

I'd like to execute Cucumber features from within Ruby code.

Typically the `cucumber` binary installed with the gem is executed on the command line with one or more features specified.

However, I'd like to define logic that creates a dynamic feature execution flow. In other words, the program can work out which features should be executed.

Is it possible to instantiate Cucumber with specified feature files from Ruby code as opposed to the command line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I discovered how from the mailing list and some API reading.

```
features="path/to/first.feature path/to/second.feature"
runtime = Cucumber::Runtime.new 
runtime.load_programming_language('rb') 
Cucumber::Cli::Main.new([features]).execute!(runtime)
```

If you want all features within your gem's `features/` directory to be executed, pass an empty array to `Main.new` instead.

Comment: Is there any way i can pass certain parameters? My configuration requires certain command line arguments to start executing the tests?

Comment: You can see [from the source](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb) that the `[features]` I pass form an `args` argument. This is parsed by [cucumber/cli/configuration](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb) using the [cucumber/cli/options](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb) class. So you can probably just append parameters onto the end of the `features` string in my example. Please confirm for others whether that works.

Comment: I tried the way you told me. At the end of the feature name, i just added the cucumber profile which i want to use with -P option. but i got an error 'Invalid argument 'xyz.feature --color -r features -p test_profile'. So it is getting passed to the method, but throwing exception.

Comment: Here is the stack trace: <code>
in `initialize'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.16/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:58:in `open'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.16/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:58:in `source'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.16/lib/cucumber/feature_file.rb:37:in `parse'
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/cucumber-</code>

Comment: Try sticking each argument in the args array instead, like so: `[features, '--color', '-r features', '-p test_profile']`. Or perhaps [`features, '--color', '-r', 'features', '-p', 'test_profile']`. If neither of those works then I don't know the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to execute using code like below. [feature_name, '-p myprofile']. Now it is not executing the env.rb and because of that the World(module) i have defined under this file is not executing. Also i am getting cucumber.yml file not found while running like this. But it is working fine if i run using cucumber. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure, see whether you can provide paths to those files as additional parameters. If that works then please post details here, if it doesn't then you should really create a new question and link to this one, rather than continuing discussion in comments here.

Comment: do you know how to run a feature within a AfterConfiguration hook, so ive already initialized cucumber and want to run certain features via a ruby method

Comment: @Richlewis Comments aren't supposed to be a Q&A, make a question about it. I responded to Sukuva because it related to my own question and answer.

Answer (score 3):

To convert this example command, with features and options specified:

```
cucumber features/first.feature features/second.feature -d -f Cucumber::Formatter::Custom
```

into Ruby code, it boils down to passing Cucumber an `args` array:

```
require 'cucumber'

# Method 1 - hardcoded features
args = %w(features/first.feature features/second.feature -d -f Cucumber::Formatter::Custom)

# Method 2 - dynamic features
features = 'features/first.feature features/second.feature'
args = features.split.concat %w(-d -f Cucumber::Formatter::Custom)

# Run cucumber
begin
  Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(args).execute!
rescue SystemExit
  puts "Cucumber calls @kernel.exit(), killing your script unless you rescue"
end
```

Tested using Ruby 2.0.0p598 and Cucumber 1.3.17

Comment: do you know how to run a feature within a AfterConfiguration hook, so ive already initialized cucumber and want to run certain features via a ruby method