# change cucumber runtime options

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

Is there any way to programmatically change options for the runtime object which is used for cucumber feature execution?

In [Ruby + Cucumber: How to execute cucumber in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864670/ruby-cucumber-how-to-execute-cucumber-in-code) it is described how to run tests from ruby script, but in addition to that I need to change some runtime options like profile, etc.

Looking at the source code a can see that there is a `runtime.configure` method, but I do not know which option to pass in to change anything.

Any help regarding this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Rake` file like the one below and pass your options

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new :features do |t|
  t.cucumber_opts = "*.feature -f json -o cucumber.json"
end
```

Comment: I actually was looking for a solution which doesnt involve calling a shell command, but passing variables with the rake command will give enough flexibility for now